# PHP Create Multidimensional Array from Corresponding Counts Array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, corresponding-records

Using PHP (7.1) with the following data and nested loops, I'm trying to get each host to match the corresponding number in the COUNTS array.

```
HOSTS:
Array ( 
  0 => 'example/search?results1'
  1 => 'thisone/search?results2'
  2 => 'thesetoo/search?results3'
)

COUNTS:
Array (
  0 => '3'
  1 => '5'
  2 => '7'
)

foreach ( $counts as $count ) {
  foreach ( $hosts as $host ) {
  $t = $count;
    for ($n=0; $n<$t; $n++) {
      $results[] = ++$host;
    }
  continue 2;
  }
}
```

`echo 'THESE ARE ALL THE RESULTS:',PHP_EOL,PHP_EOL,var_dump($results);`

RESULTS I'M LOOKING FOR:
MULTIDIMENSIONAL ARRAY

```
Array (
0 => Array (
    0 => 'example/search?results1'
    1 => 'example/search?results1'
    2 => 'example/search?results1'
    )
1 => Array (
    0 => 'thisone/search?results2'
    1 => 'thisone/search?results2'
    2 => 'thisone/search?results2'
    3 => 'thisone/search?results2'
    4 => 'thisone/search?results2'
    )
2 => Array (
    0 => 'thesetoo/search?results3'
    1 => 'thesetoo/search?results3'
    2 => 'thesetoo/search?results3'
    3 => 'thesetoo/search?results3'
    4 => 'thesetoo/search?results3'
    5 => 'thesetoo/search?results3'
    6 => 'thesetoo/search?results3'
    )
)
```

Notice the number of results per HOSTS corresponds to the COUNTS array.

In the nested for loops above, I'm either getting just one host for all counts or every count for all hosts in a single dimension array.  What I need is a multi-dimensional array, but the nested for loop logic is escaping me.  I've tried both continue and break in the loops, but no luck.  If the loop gets another count, then it skips the host.  If it gets another host, then it skips the count.

There is no pattern to either the hosts or the counts array.  These will always correspond to each other but they will be random strings/numbers.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: What is the expected out of the array?

Comment: What you see above is the desired output from the 2 corresponding arrays.

Comment: Wow! All great answers below.  I'm running tests on all of them.  Just need a few hours for final results.  Thank you!

Comment: Please upvote this question so I can get a couple more reputation points. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if count of `$hosts` and `$counts` equals:

```
$result = [];
foreach ($hosts as $i => $host) {
    $result[] = array_fill(0, $counts[$i], $host);
}
```

Comment: `foreach ($hosts as $i => $host) {`

Comment: The simplicity of your answer is the best.  What would you suggest for appending strings to the end of each host string in this?  For example, instead of returning only 3 of the same string from the first array combination, what about returning a unique string for each of the 3.  Like this:

    array(3) {
      [0]=>
    array(3) {
      [0]=> string(67) "example/search?results100"
      [1]=> string(67) "example/search?results200"
      [2]=> string(67) "example/search?results300"
      }
    }

Notice the 3 different integers on each tail.

Comment: you can append any string to `$host` like this `$result[] = array_fill(0, $counts[$i], $host . 'example');`

Comment: Thank you. That would work for a static append, but what about a dynamic integer like 100, 200, 300 for each result?

Comment: for this we can't use `array_fill` this function generates array with same values, so use `for` loop to fill arrays

Comment: I'm coming to the same conclusion and running some tests now.  Thank you.  Please upvote my question.

Answer (score 2):

This question is the perfect usage example for [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) and [`array_fill()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-fill.php).

```
$hosts = array(
  0 => 'example/search?results1',
  1 => 'thisone/search?results2',
  2 => 'thesetoo/search?results3',
);

$counts = array(
  0 => '3',
  1 => '5',
  2 => '7',
);

$result = array_map(
    function($host, $count) {
        return array_fill(0, $count, $host);
    },
    $hosts,
    $counts
);
```

Comment: Can a dynamic integer be appended to the host string with your array_map function?  For example, can each result have a 100, 200, 300 or any other integer appended dynamically?

Comment: Anything can be done if it is specified clearly. Take into consideration that I cannot read your mind.

Comment: I know I didn't include this in the question, but specifically, can your `array_map` with `array_fill` handle dynamic code?  Could I take another array of dynamic numbers and assign them to each result?

Comment: Some things can be done (by passing more arguments to [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) or by using closures or by other means), others cannot be done this way. Do you have in mind a specific use case? Describe it in a new question.

Comment: Thank you, I'm posting the new question right now.  I'll send you the link.

Comment: Here's the link to the new question: [php-create-multiple-arrays-from-string-using-search-array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47084459/php-create-multiple-arrays-from-string-using-search-array)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$hosts = array ( 
  0 => 'example/search?results1',
  1 => 'thisone/search?results2',
  2 => 'thesetoo/search?results3'
);

$counts = array (
  0 => '3',
  1 => '5',
  2 => '7'
);

$results =array();
foreach ( $counts as $count ) { 
    $key_of_count = array_search( $count, $counts ); 
    for ($i=0; $i < (int)$count; $i++) {
        $results[$key_of_count][] = $hosts[$key_of_count];
    }
}
echo "<pre>"; print_r($results); echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: In my data, I have multiple counts that are the same integer. In your example, this combined similar integer values together into one, but anything different produced correct results.  For example, if you add another 3 to the COUNTS array above, it will combine with the adjacent 3 and make it one large array of only 1 URL.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for way that is done using only loops and not using any fancy array functions, then this might be the answer you are looking for:

```
$result = [];

foreach($counts as $k=>$count){
  $result[$k]='';
    for($i=0; $i < $count; $i++){
        $result[$k][] = $hosts[$k];
    }
}
```

Comment: This returns only 1 result per URL, and not the designated number from the COUNTS array.